# Insert date to mysql with node

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm currently trying to get the current date and try to save on my database but the only thing i get on my date column is 1982 , really strange ? Here is my code for the date and the mysql insertion :

DATE :

```
var dateTime = require('node-datetime')
var dt = dateTime.create();
var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d');
console.log(formatted);
```

Mysql insertion :

```
pool.query(
    'INSERT INTO jbets SET user = ' + pool.escape(tradingRequests[offer.id]['user']) + 
    ', assetids = ' + pool.escape(assetidsSS) + 
    ', value = ' + pool.escape(totalPrice) + 
    ', minTicket = ' + pool.escape(minTicket) + 
    ', maxTicket = ' + pool.escape(maxTicket) + 
    ', total = ' + pool.escape(totalSkins) + 
    ', jid = ' + pool.escape(jackpotRound) + 
    ', token = ' + pool.escape(offer.id) + 
    ',date =' + formatted
)
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Node's MySQL interface, but I think you are not using prepared statements.  Consider using them to avoid such possible errors.

Answer (score 4):

1. You should really be using placeholders.
2. You shouldn't be trying to convert the date object to that string format before inserting into a date field in the DB. The proper format would be `YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss`, however you could let your MySQL library handle the conversion for you.

I suggest reading the [Escaping Query Values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) section of the MySQL JS library documentation.

Try something like this:

```
  pool.query('INSERT INTO jbets SET user = ?, assetids = ?, value = ?, ' +
            'minTicket = ?, maxTicket = ?, total = ?, jid = ?, token = ?, date = ?', 
            [tradingRequests[offer.id]['user'], assetidsSS, totalPrice, 
             minTicket, maxTicket, totalSkins, jackpotRound, offer.id, dt]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

`pool.query('INSERT INTO jbets (user, assetids, value, minTicket, maxTicket, total, jid, token, date) VALUES(pool.escape(tradingRequests[offer.id]['user']), pool.escape(assetidsSS), pool.escape(totalPrice), pool.escape(minTicket), pool.escape(maxTicket), pool.escape(totalSkins), pool.escape(jackpotRound), pool.escape(offer.id), NOW()));`

Comment: Even if the code works, an explanation is always great when accompanying it.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for responding the problem was from my db i was need to change the ty to varchar